# Can I migrate from an unencrypted postgres DB to an encrypted one using pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I want to migrate some tables from an unencrypted RDS Postgres database to a new encrypted RDS Postgres database. `pg_dump` or `COPY` seems the best option to me, my understanding is it's more of logical replication so after `pg_restore` it should be encrypted in new database. Is that true?

Comment: They have instructions for encrypting an unencrypted db by copying the unencrypted snapshot here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

Comment: But generally, yes once you create the encrypted db you can restore/copy another (unencrypted) db dump into it

Comment: @melcher the tricky part is I don't want to encrypt the original db (that db will still be used by others), i could create an encrypted snapshot but it adds complexity as i need to count for data written after creating snapshot

Comment: i don't understand.... you want an encrypted db **and** an unencrypted db that have the same data and stay in sync but are used by different users?

Comment: @melcher im moving only some tables out of the old db to the new db; the old db will continue serving rest of the tables

Comment: So I would create a snapshot, migrate the entire db over to the encrypted db, then drop the extra tables (from both sides). Would that work?

Comment: the encrypted db already have some existing tables, so i prefer not tearing it down. My guess is pgdump and copy will just work given it's logical replication?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236629/discussion-between-melcher-and-james-yu).